# passport.authenticate('local'), giving jwt is not defined

Tags: express, passport.js

I am trying to use passport.authenticate('local') like this

```
 exports.doLogin = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    if (!req.body.username) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: "Username was not given" })
    } else {
        passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: err })
            } else {
                console.log('in ok 1', user)
                if (!user) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: 'username or password incorrect' })
                } else {
                    req.login(user, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('dddddddd', err);
                            res.json({ success: false, message: err.message, temp: '111' })
                        } else {
                            const token = jwt.sign({
                                userId: user._id,
                                username: user.username
                            }, secretkey,
                                { expiresIn: '24h' })
                            res.json({ success: true, message: "Authentication  successful", token: token });
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })(req, res);
    }
}
```

But i am getting reponse like this:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "jwt is not defined",
    "temp": "111"
}
```

Need some help

Comment: to use `jwt.sign` you need to include the lib

Comment: ok, i got it, i forgot that.